# What will happen if I enable LDAP authenticaion on pfsense and LDAP server will fail?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, pfsense, aaa

Currently I am using local database for authentication on my pfsense. I know that Cisco's IOS has backup authentication methods for the cases when primary one fails. You can even not to authenticate at all if all servers fail.
I want to use AD user base to organize the user control, but here is a question, what will happen when AD fails, can pfsense jump to local database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, pfSense will try a local account – after a long delay until the connection times out.

(There were fixes regarding this in 2.4-git, but in current release versions everything will be slow.)

Comment: thanks, any ideas how long does "long" mean?

Comment: I think somewhere around 15/30/60 seconds if the server is down (not responding).

Comment: You can set the timeout in configuration. It has been reduced to 5 seconds by default in one of the 2.3.x releases.